# Create wordpress function to get post author gravatar url as template tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I need a code implemented within function.php so I can get post author gravatar url as template tag `get_author_gravatar_url()`.

So far I am using template tag `my_gravatar_url()` using function:

```
function my_gravatar_url() { // Get user email
$user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' );
/* Convert email into md5 hash and set image size to 65 px */
$user_gravatar_url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5($user_email) . '?s=150';
echo $user_gravatar_url; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to modify the function slightly to `return` the value (rather than displaying it):

```
function get_author_gravatar_url() { 
    // Get user email
    $user_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' );
    // Convert email into md5 hash and set image size to 65 px
    $user_gravatar_url = 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5($user_email) . '?s=150';

    return $user_gravatar_url; 
}
```